# C# high score in game

Tags: c#

Bassicaly I'm stucked with displaying high scores via listbox by discending order(like 500 to 1). Here is my code, keep in mind that label1 is score in the game, so if anyone may help me please?

```
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Form2.passingText;

        StreamWriter q = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\BS\\Desktop\\tex.txt", true);
        q.WriteLine(label1.Text);
        q.Close();


        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\BS\\Desktop\\tex.txt");
        string g = sr.ReadLine();
        while (g != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(g);

            g = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It really would help if you showed us what `label1.Text` or `tex.txt` contained.

Comment: label1.Text contains score you achieved in game... and tex.txt is a file connecter with StreamReader and Writer to keep those scores because I have to use StreamReader and Writer for this project. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read file as list of lines and then sort it using Linq
So, instead of using `SteamReader`, try this:

```
using System.Linq;
//....

List<string> hiscores = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\BS\\Desktop\\tex.txt").ToList();
hiscores.Sort();
foreach (string s in hiscores)
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
```

EDIT:
since you have to use StreamReader, here is this approach (but the principle is same):

```
    List<string> hiscores = new List<string>();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\BS\\Desktop\\tex.txt");
    string g = sr.ReadLine();
    while (g != null)
    {
        hiscores.Add(g);
        g = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    hiscores.Sort();
    hiscores.Reverse();
    //alternatively, instead of Sort and then reverse, you can do
    //hiscores.OrderByDescending(x => x);

    foreach(string s in hiscores)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Comment: I appriciate your help, but please I need to use StreamReader for this project so if anyone know how?

Comment: Thank you again but it is again in ascending order which I was able to achieve by selecting sort to true, but I need in descending order like i have scores 420, 490, 120, 320, to be like 490, 420, 320, 120, I'm begginer so maybe your code is good but I didn't use it properly or you misunderstood me..

Anyona else with solution please?

Comment: a have edited my answer again. After sort, you have reverse order with `hiscores.Reverse()`. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you man, you are my hero! Thanks for your time an patience.
I have trying to do the same with reverse but instead to put highscores.Reverse() like you did bellow highscores.Sort() I have replaced that, once again thanks you man!

Comment: Mark my answer as solution is the best way to say thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry I am new here so I don't know how to do that, but if you explain me I would do that for sure, that is at least what I can do for you :D

I selected this green tick I hope that's it and gave you a thumbs up..